# "http://<machineName>:<port>..://" Is this valid url in CloseableHttpClient?

Tags: java, http, url, browser, httpclient

I am able to get 200 status code for "http://machineName:port..://".
But same url format is not running in postman or normal browser. I have to validate this wrong format url but http response is not throwing any exception so how to solve this problem.
I am using CloseableHttpClient class.
This url "http://machineName:port[alphanumeric]/" also passed (got 200 status code).

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a valid URL. Apparently `CloseableHttpClient`'s implementation is very forgiving and parses this anyways.

Comment: So this is not good way for customer end right? @f1sh

Comment: I don't see how your choice of an http client during testing has an impact on any customer